# Ads/CFT coordinates

Tags: ads-cft

I have an AdS space written in Poincare' coordinates and in global coordinates. The transformation that brings one set in the other is a conformal transformation?

Comment: No, it's a coordinate transformation which is more general than conformal transformation. I think you cannot write a relation between two metrics like $g^\text{global}_{\mu\nu}=\Omega^2g^\text{Poincare}_{\mu\nu}$.